# How to get file path of most recently used simulator & most recently updated app on an iOS simulator in Bash?

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

It can be useful (or necessary) to know the full path on a mac of a given iOS simulator app.  E.g., I have an iOS app with sqlite and want an easy way to build a connection string for debugging with DBeaver. Most of the time the criteria is "where on the mac is the path to the most recently run simulator & most recently built app on it?".  How do I get this in bash?

Answer (score 0):

```
# id of most recent device
device=$(ls -lt ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ | head -2 | tail -1 | awk 'NF{print $NF; exit}')

# id of most recent app
app=$(ls -lt ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"$device"/data/Containers/Data/Application | head -2 | tail -1 | awk 'NF{print $NF; exit}')

# the full path
fullpath=$(ls ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"$device"/data/Containers/Data/Application/"$app"/)

echo $fullpath
```